# one-hot-encoding categorical data gives error

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, pandas, kaggle

I am currently working on the Boston problem hosted on Kaggle.  The dataset is nothing like the Titanic dataset.  There are many categorical columns and I'm trying to one-hot-encode these columns.  I've decided to go with the column `MSZoning` to get the approach working and work out a strategy to apply it to other categorical columns.  This is a small snippet of the dataset:

[image]

Here are the different types of values present in `MSZoning`, so obviously integer encoding only would be a bad idea:

`['RL' 'RM' 'C (all)' 'FV' 'RH']`

Here is my attempt on Python to assign `MSZoning` with the new one-hot-encoded data.  I do know that one-hot-encoding turns each value into a column of its own and assigns binary values to each of them so I realize that this isn't exactly a good idea.  I wanted to try it anyways:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder


train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/master/train.csv")

labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()

train['MSZoning'] = labelEncoder.fit_transform(train['MSZoning'])
train_OHE = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=train['MSZoning'])
train['MSZoning'] = train_OHE.fit_transform(train['MSZoning']).toarray()


print(train['MSZoning'])
```

Which is giving me the following (obvious) error:

```
C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py:392: DeprecationWarning: The 'categorical_features' keyword is deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. You can use the ColumnTransformer instead.
  "use the ColumnTransformer instead.", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Boston-Kaggle/Boston.py", line 11, in <module>
    train['MSZoning'] = train_OHE.fit_transform(train['MSZoning']).toarray()
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 511, in fit_transform
    self._handle_deprecations(X)
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 394, in _handle_deprecations
    n_features = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I did read through some Medium posts on this but they didn't exactly relate to what I was trying to do with my dataset as they were working with dummy data with a couple of categorical columns.  What I want to know is, how do I make use of one-hot-encoding after the (attempted) step?

Comment: Quick note: you have loaded the same dataframe for both `train` and `test`

Comment: I've been displeased with how OneHotEncoder works based on hot LabelEncoder works. like the accepted answer, `pd.get_dummies` does OneHotEncoding without the (unnecessary) hassle of setting up the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I noticed you have loaded the same dataframe for both `train` and `test`. Change the code like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/master/test.csv")
```

At this point, one-hot encode each variable you want with `pandas`' `get_dummies()` function:

```
# Onhe-hot encode a given variable
OHE_MSZoning = pd.get_dummies(train['MSZoning'])
```

It will be returned as a `pandas` dataframe. In my Jupyter Notebook it looks like this:

```
OHE_MSZoning.head()
```

[image]

You can repeat the same command for all the variables you want to one-hot encode.

Hope this helps, otherwise let me know.

Comment: How come you're using `pandas.get_dummies()` over the sklearn function?

Comment: It's the method I'm used to, I work all the time with pandas dataframes and I find it useful. But it's not necessarily better than sklearn. I used this because I'm sure it worked.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try.  Thank you.  I'll accept your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote?

Comment: So do you just create a new variable for every instance of this?  This dataset has many categorical variables.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach using the encoders from sklearn

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/master/test.csv")
```

```py
labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
MSZoning_label = labelEncoder.fit_transform(train['MSZoning'])
```

The order mapping of classes and labels from sklearn's LabelEncoder can be seen from its `classes_` property

```py
labelEncoder.classes_
```

```
array(['C (all)', 'FV', 'RH', 'RL', 'RM'], dtype=object)
```

```py
onehotEncoder = OneHotEncoder(n_values=len(labelEncoder.classes_))
MSZoning_onehot_sparse = onehotEncoder.fit_transform([MSZoning_label])
```

- Convert `MSZoning_onehot` from sparse array to dense array
- Reshape the dense array to be `(n_classes,n_examples)`
- Convert from float to int type

```py
MSZoning_onehot = MSZoning_onehot_sparse.toarray().reshape(len(MSZoning_label),-1).astype(int)
```

Pack it back into a data frame if you wan't

```py
MSZoning_label_onehot = pd.DataFrame(MSZoning_onehot,columns=labelEncoder.classes_)
MSZoning_label_onehot.head(10)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get this line `array(['C (all)', 'FV', 'RH', 'RL', 'RM'], dtype=object)`.  MSZoning is already type object.

Comment: That is the output of the line above it.
`In [1]: print(labelEncoder.classes_)`
`Out[2]: array(['C (all)', 'FV', 'RH', 'RL', 'RM'], dtype=object)`

Comment: When you pack it back into the dataframe, the dataframe isn't `train`.  Shouldn't you submit your OHE variables back into the mother data?

Comment: I created a new dataframe in the example, but you can add it back to the `train` dataframe if you like. The indexes between the two are mapped.